# i can't use display name on minecraft 1.13+

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

@a[scores={drink_any=1},nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:potion"},tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"Fresh Water"}'}}}]

don't work!!!
I maked wrong on display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tag:{...} is a part of the item's nbt so it should be in the nbt tag.

```
@a[scores={drink_any=1},nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:potion",tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"Fresh Water"}'}}}}]
```

Comment: thank you very much i didn't see this wrong